# Can i use views to insert or update two tables

Tags: c#, sql-server, t-sql

I have created a view to display data from two table to use it in C# winforms but is it possible to perform insert and update to this view so that the tables will updated?

Here is the function I used

```
CREATE VIEW BOM
AS
    SELECT 
        A.[bomItem], A.bomRev, A.qty, A.partId,
        B.[WO RIM LOOKUP H], B.SUPPLIER, B.[SUPPLIER PN], 
        B.[RIM DIAMETER], B.[RIM WIDTH], B.SIZE, B.[STOCK NO]
    FROM
        BOMD A 
    JOIN
        RIMS B ON A.[partId] = B.[STOCK NO]
```

Comment: You have to be more specific. for example what UI control you use.

Comment: using form or Grid Control in Devexpress

Comment: have you gone through tutorials like this https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/bethmassi/2008/10/15/editing-data-from-two-tables-in-a-single-datagridview/

Comment: If you're using T-SQL view, check the [Updatable Views](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187956.aspx) section for limitations

Comment: Thank you guys, I will try both options good input

Answer (score 0):

Only a singe table of the view can be modified directly by DML. However, you can create an INSTEAD OF trigger on the view and perform the needed modifications in the trigger. This allows the view to appear behave like a table to your C# code.